# Is it possible to reverse `orderBy` in BitBucket Server API for git tags?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

Playing with Bitbucket Server API, I found [these docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.14.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45888278802496) regarding git tags:

> ```
> /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/tags?filterText&orderBy
> ```
>
> orderBy: string: ordering of refs either ALPHABETICAL (by name) or MODIFICATION (last updated)

What I want is the *reverse* alphabetical order.

In some different part of API docs I found [the following info](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering)

> You can sort result sets using the ?sort= query parameter, available
>   on the same resources that support filtering:
>
> By default the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, prefix
>   the field name with a hyphen (e.g. ?sort=-updated_on).

but it seems this trick doesn't work for `orderBy`; when I try `orderBy=-ALPHABETICAL`, it's the same as `orderBy=ALPHABETICAL`.

Is it possible to revert the order somehow?

Answer (score 1):

your first link is a documentation for Bitbucket server API v1.0.

I'm assuming that it should work as is if you are really making your request against this version of the API.
Moreover, bitbucket server refers to the self-hosted version of Bitbucket, and i don't know if the public Bitbucket shares the same API in v1.

However, the second link you present is part of Bitbucket API v2.0 documentation.
In the Querying -> Refs (Branches/Tags/Bookmarks) section of the page, you can see that you can use the 'name' field as filter or sort field, that contains the tag name while querying tags. The correct syntax is shown near the top of the page.
I'm assuming you want to query the public API v2.0.

So to resume:

**Bitbucket Server API v1.0**

`/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/tags?orderBy=-ALPHABETICAL`

**Bitbucket Public API v2.0**

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/refs/tags?sort=-name`